# why webpack/encore symfony adds public/build in gitignore?

Tags: git, symfony, webpack-encore, platform.sh

I have *webpack/encore* installed on my symfony project.

*public/build* has been added to *gitignore* but when I deploy on a PaaS like platform.sh, without this folder, my website design is broken.

Should I remove *public/build* folder from *gitignore* ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's intended to [build the assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#how-do-i-deploy-my-encore-assets) on a build server or the production server. You can comment out `public/build/` but be sure to build the production environment assets prior to deployment. `./node_modules/.bin/encore production` You're also expected to run `composer install --no-dev` on the production side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform.sh is designed to have first-class support for your git workflow. So, I'm sure if you added `.gitignore` it was for a good reason.

Wherever your app is defined (`.platform.app.yaml` or `.platform/applications.yaml`) you will want to:

1. Ensure your [build hoook](https://docs.platform.sh/create-apps/hooks.html#build-dependencies) is generating your public/build assets.
2. That your [locations](https://docs.platform.sh/create-apps/app-reference.html#locations) and `root` is properly configured to handle requests made to your app so that request to your website are handled appropriately.

With this in place, from your local machine (and after deployment) run `platform ssh` and check to make sure your public/build files exist.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the ignore because you must install and build the assets in your server.

You must first install all dependences and then build your assets.
In your root document add this file .platform.app.yaml

```
//.platform.app.yaml
name: node-app
type: nodejs:16
disk: 512

dependencies:
    nodejs:
        yarn: "*"

hooks:
    build: |
        npm install --force
        npm run build
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I am a beginner on Paas deployment and missed the build hook. I will check my platform config file.

Comment: Ok! Very good. Please reply if you have other questions.